# Cant reset MySQL root password window 10

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I tried to use this solution by use this console command **mysqld --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt** and it start the **mysqld.exe** and i can connect to the database with the new password. But after start, it not start the MySQL service and if i stop the **mysqld.ex`** and then start the service,the password is the old one.So how can i reset the password in the right way.Please help.I using MySQL8.0

**mysql-init file**

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
```

Comment: what is the context of mysql-init.txt? What mysql version? Did you look at [manual on resetting permission](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) adjusting URL for the major MySQL version you are using?

Comment: @danblack hi,i do the same thing with your suggest url before,after a hour i can have a solution which work for me.i delete the data folder and my.ini file in the programdata->mysql->mysqlserver 8.0 and do the same thing as above.finally it work.Is the my.ini file or data contain the old password?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the standard steps：

1: Turn off mysqld (service process) through task manager or service management

2: Start mysqld through the command line + special parameters. Note that the path here can be replaced with your ini path.

```sql
mysqld --defaults-file="D:\Program Files\mysql\MySQLServer8.0Data\my.ini" --skip-grant-tables
```

3: At this point, the mysqld service process has been opened. and does not require permission checks

4: mysql -uroot Log in to the server without a password. Start another client for

5: Modify the permission table

```sql
use mysql;

update user set authentication_string=password('new password') where user='root' and Host='localhost';

flush privileges;
```

6: Turn off the mysqld service process through the task manager.

7: Open the mysql service through the service management again, and you can log in with the modified new password.

Finally, have you tried `update` and `flush privileges;`?

Comment: it's very long time ago and now i moved to Full stack mobile app developer and i don't rememmber about this one. Thanks you for reply btw <3